# Javascript change HTML in certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, addclass

I am working on taking a current site and turning it into a drupal site. I am working with Javascript that was written before so I'm trying to slightly modify it to work.

Currently wherever there is a paragraph tag it inserts a class. I want to fine tune it so it only adds to class to the paragraph tag within a certain div class "submenu". Any suggestions how I can achieve that?

this is the current site functionality: http://gattimorrison.com/manufacturers.php

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).find("p").each(function(i) {
            $(this).addClass("imgMa"+i);
            $(this).hover(function() {
                $("#nameMa"+i).addClass("red");
                $("#nameMa"+i).append("<span class='dot'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>");
                $(this).removeClass("imgMa"+i);
                $(this).addClass("imgMa"+i+"_on");
            }, function() {
                $("#nameMa"+i).removeClass("red");
                $("span.dot").remove();
                $(this).removeClass("imgMa"+i+"_on");
                $(this).addClass("imgMa"+i);
            });

        });

        $(document).find("li").each(function(i) {
            $(this).hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("red");
                $(this).append("<span class='dot'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>");
                $("#imgMa"+i).removeClass("imgMa"+i);
                $("#imgMa"+i).addClass("imgMa"+i+"_on");
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("red");
                $("span.dot").remove();
                $("#imgMa"+i).removeClass("imgMa"+i+"_on");
                $("#imgMa"+i).addClass("imgMa"+i);
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `http://gattimorrison.com/manufMO.php`, `http://gattimorrison.com/manufPR.php` Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the selector that targets the p.

```
$(document).find(".submenu p").each(function(i) {
```